# Finding Minimum from List of data

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of data in the form `data = {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3},...}` and I would like to find the value of x for when y is minimum from the data set, ideally in the form `{x,ymin}`. What is the easiest way to go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `data//Pick[#, #[[All,2]], Min@#[[All,2]]]&`, maybe, but there are many ways ...

Comment: Another way is sorting the list with respect to the second coordinate and then take the first element: SortBy[data, #[[2]] &][[1]]

Comment: `MinimalBy[data,Last]`

Comment: These methods work well, thanks very much!

Comment: Another option is to use: ```First[TakeSmallestBy[data, Last, 1]]```